# Is this a security question or a networking question?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

[Possible to determine who on the Internet is resetting (RST) my TCP connection?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/271361/possible-to-determine-who-on-the-internet-is-resetting-rst-my-tcp-connection)

To me, this is a pure networking question. "How to find where in the traffic flow the RST is happening" is resolved by networking techniques. The fact that the experiment is about TLS and involves the manipulating of the SNI seems secondary. Which means the primary issue is the network flow.

However, there might be some utility in having this particular experiment (and resulting tests) on our site.

I'm happy to get your feedback and reasonings.

Answer (score 1):

While it is interesting to network security folks, it is just a networking question. I would expect any good network engineer, even those with no security responsibility, to be able to manage all the activities in that post.